# How can I change multiple values at once in pandas dataframe, using arrays as indices that vary in length?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to change a number of values in my pandas dataframe, where the indices that are indicating the columns may vary in size.

I need something that is faster than a for-loop, because it will be done on a lot of rows, and this turned out to be too slow.

As a simple example, consider this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((5,5)))
```

Now, I want to change some of the values in this dataframe to 1. If I e.g. want to change the values in  the second and fith row for the first two columns, but in the fourth row I want to change all the values, I want something like this to work:

```
col_indices = np.array([np.arange(2),np.arange(5),np.arange(2)]) 


row_indices = np.array([1,3,4]) 


df.loc(row_indices,col_indices) =1
```

However, this does not work (I suspect that it does not work because the shape of the data you would select is not conform with a dataframe).

Is there any more flexible way of indexing without having to loop over rows etc.?

A solution that works only for range-like arrays (as above) would also work for my current problem - but general answer would also be nice.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC here's one approach. Define  the column indices as the amount of columns where you want to insert `1s` instead, and the rows where you want to insert them:

```
col_indices = np.array([2,5,2])
row_indices = np.array([1,3,4]) 
arr = df.values
```

And use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) to set the cells of interest to `1`:

```
arr[row_indices] = np.arange(arr.shape[0]) <= col_indices[:,None]

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for my problem! Do you know by any chance a solution for the general case ? Or isn't there any?